# Android - InvalidKeySpecException - java lang runtime exception SSLInternal:TOO_LONG when trying to read .der file

Tags: java, android, encryption, private-key, der

I am trying to read a **private key** from a der file. I am getting the following error in my logcat. And the returned value is empty.

**java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.lang.RuntimeException: error:0c0000af:ASN.1 encoding routines:OPENSSL_internal:TOO_LONG**

I tried searching for situations where this had already happened but could find none. I would like to know what this error means and how I can solve it.

Here is my code:

```
public static String decryptionWithFile(String encrypted,String privateFile2)throws Exception  {
    PrivateKey privateKey = getPrivateKey(privateFile2);

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
    byte[] bts = Hex.decodeHex(encrypted.toCharArray());
    bts = cipher.doFinal(bts);


    bts = getFinalBytesOfDycryptedString(bts);
    String decryptedMessage = new String(cipher.doFinal(encrypted.getBytes()));
    return new String(bts,"UTF-8");
}
```

And here is the getPrivateKey(); Method:

```
private static PrivateKey getPrivateKey(String privateFile2)throws Exception  {
    File f = new File(privateFile2);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
    byte[] keyBytes = new byte[(int) f.length()];
    dis.readFully(keyBytes);
    dis.close();
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
    RSAPrivateKey privKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyFactory.generatePrivate(spec);
    return privKey;
}
```

***Important Note: I added the .der file to my assets folder and then saved it to a file in Internal Storage in order to access the path - which my function requires. Do you think, anything must have happened to the file during this process? (It worked fine with the Public Key)***

Comment: Are you getting the privatekey correctly from file. Have you checked it by printing in log??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be what I'd guessed. When I was writing the .der file to the Internal Storage, it was getting altered somehow and thus wasn't working.

So instead of that. I directly used the `InputStream` returned from getAssets().open(filename) to read the private key. That fixed it.